# No changes in DropDownList

Tags: c#, .net, drop-down-menu

Goal:
The user should not make any changes in the text field in Combobox.

Problem:
I don't want the user to make any changes in the text field. I want the user to make a selection in the DropDownList without any text changes. The same concept will be as ListBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your DropDownStyle property to "DropDownList" for your ComboBox.

Answer (score 1):

Change the [DropDownStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.dropdownstyle.aspx) property to [`ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.comboboxstyle.aspx)